# How to download image from Google userinfo respones?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I want each player to have their google profile picture as their avatar. So i thougth i could use the link from userinfo to embed it on the my website.

I am able to login (via https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth) and get data from the userinfo api (via https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo), but when I try and get the picture I get a 400 bad request response.

The picture url: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AD_cMMTQxBdVdae_-uIPzOwrjfiPwPplpdS11g9xMrgFNDJHMqc%5Cu003ds96-c

The acces token has these scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- openid

I tried using the acces token in the Authorization header even though it should be public anyways, but no luck. I also tried searching for documentation but couldn't find anything for googleusercontent.com

Comment: Try going though the people api its easier.   Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: there is not realy any code. just testing via postman and my browser. i will add more specifiecs about the params and repsonses. i will also have a look at that other api

Comment: Are these the docs for that api? (https://developers.google.com/people) It looks like it just works with conntacts of other peaple. I want the image for each account on my website to be their linked google profile pic. so they will not allways be contacts.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get   pass it people/me and you will get the current users profile information.    Userinfo endpoint doesnt always return the data you want.

Comment: nvm i got it working with the peaple api. Why don't those two api's give me the same link tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out i should have used this api instead:

- https://developers.google.com/people
- https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

Using the same token, the id from userinfo and personFields=photos I get a public link to the picture: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AAcHTtcasJNL-UkJ7S3uNGtNpQvwigQI_z3vQOle6zFlm7Zx7fA=s100